# OneDrive.open() redirects to my own page instead of OneDrive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, onedrive

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const KEY = 'id'; // <-- filled in.

const OneDrivePicker = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Load the OneDrive SDK asynchronously
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      // The OneDrive SDK is now loaded
      console.log('OneDrive SDK loaded');
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      // Cleanup script tag on component unmount
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);
  const handleCancel = () => console.log('CANCELLED');

  const handleSuccess = (files: any) => console.log('SUCCESS: ', files);

  const handleError = (err: any) => console.log('ERROR: ', err);

  const launchOneDrivePicker = () => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const odOptions = {
        clientId: KEY,
        action: 'download',
        multiSelect: true,
        openInNewWindow: true,
        advanced: {},
        success: (files: any) => {
          handleSuccess(files);
          resolve();
        },
        cancel: () => {
          handleCancel();
          reject();
        },
        error: (e: any) => {
          handleError(e);
          reject();
        },
      };

      if (OneDrive) {
        OneDrive.open(odOptions);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={launchOneDrivePicker}>
      Click
    </button>
  );
};

export default OneDrivePicker;
```

I try to run this code, but somehow the popup will open to my own page instead of OneDrive. Does some know how I can solve this?

I came across this page with the same issue: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1254 ,but the thread is closed and there was no solution provided that helped me out.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/open-file?view=odsp-graph-online#3-launch-the-file-picker

Another example **that works** but ***not in Typescript but Javascript:*** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/onedrive-filepicker-prototype-1-n0zu0?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A5%2C25

*update:*

I can visit the One Drive page if I add

```
advanced: {
          endpointHint: 'api.onedrive.com',
          accessToken: aToken // <-- not sure what to fill in
        },
```

but after selecting a file I do get an error:

```
{ errorCode: "webRequestFailure", message: "HTTP error status: 401", apiEndpoint: "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/" }
```